# If $f(3) = 5$, write an ordered pair that must be on the graph of $y=f(x+5)+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone please help me to understand how to solve this problem? Thank you.

If $f(3) = 5$, write an ordered pair that must be on the graph of $y=f(x+5)+1$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x = -2$, then $f(-2+5) = f(3) = 5$. So $$y = f(-2+5)+1 = f(3)+1 = 5+1 = 6$$Therefore an ordered pair is $(-2,6)$.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I tried this with a similar problem but am having problems.

If f(4) = 2, write an ordered pair that must be on the graph of y=f(x+4)-5

If x=0, then f(0+4) = f(4) = 4

y = f(0+4)-5 = f(4)-5 = 4-5 = -1

Correct answer is 0 -3 but can anyone explain where I went wrong?

Comment: $$y = f(0+4)-5 = f(4)-5 = 2-5 = -3$$ You went wrong by saying that $f(4) = 4$